# how to add annotations to kubernetes node using patch_file

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, longhorn

I want to start learning to deploy longhorn to my exixting on-perm kubernetes

As in https://longhorn.io/docs/1.3.1/advanced-resources/default-disk-and-node-config/#launch-longhorn-with-multiple-disks , I need to add some annotations to the node

I try to use 'merge' as stated in https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/#use-a-json-merge-patch-to-update-a-deployment

Here is my patch file (lhpatch.yaml)

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    node.longhorn.io:
      default-disks-config:
      - path: /mnt/lh01
        allowSheduling: true
      - path: /mnt/lh02
        allowSheduling: true
```

Apply it:

```
kubectl patch node k8s-worker-1 --type merge --patch-file /home/bino/k0s-sriwijaya/longhorn/lhpatch.yaml
```

But I got error (at the last line of results):

```
json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field ObjectMeta.metadata.annotations of type string
```

Kindly please tell me how to fix my lhpatch.yaml

Sincerely

-bino-

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    node.longhorn.io:
      default-disks-config:
      - path: /mnt/lh01
        allowSheduling: 'true'
      - path: /mnt/lh02
        allowSheduling: 'true'
```

Since in annotations you can't refer to boolean types, and instead you should pass with `string: string`.

Comment: Thankyou for your response. I tried to follow your suggestion, but the error still there. I check the node and the annotation still the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

my fault.

annotation only accept 'string'.
My yaml have array in it.

So I think the right yaml is:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    node.longhorn.io/default-disks-config: '[{"name": "lh01", "path": "/mnt/lh01", "allowScheduling": true}, {"name": "lh02", "path": "/mnt/lh02", "allowScheduling": true}]'
```